# How do I get Atomikos JMS to work with Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, atomikos

I am using Atomikos for transactions and Weblogic for JMS.  My client is receiving JMSClientExceptions stating that getXAResource can only be called from the server. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13731/jtatximp.htm#i1060046 describes how to get Weblogic to work with a Third-Party Transaction Manager.  It states that "you must register the WebLogic Server interposed transaction manager as a subordinate with the foreign transaction manager." I am unable to figure out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you finally addressed the issue?